# Python regular expression match in html file

Tags: python, html, regex

I am trying to match inside an html file.  This is the html:

```
<td>
<b>BBcode</b><br />
<textarea onclick='this.select();' style='width:300px;     height:200px;' />
[URL=http://someimage.com/LwraZS1]          [IMG]http://t1.someimage.com/LwraZS1.jpg[/IMG][    [/URL] [URL=http://someimage.com/CDnuiST]   [IMG]http://t1.someimage.com/CDnuiST.jpg[/IMG]   [/URL] [URL=http://someimage.com/Y0oZKPb][IMG]http://t1.someimage.com/Y0oZKPb.jpg[/IMG][/URL] [URL=http://someimage.com/W2RMAOR][IMG]http://t1.someimage.com/W2RMAOR.jpg[/IMG][/URL] [URL=http://someimage.com/5e5AYUz][IMG]http://t1.someimage.com/5e5AYUz.jpg[/IMG][/URL] [URL=http://someimage.com/EWDQErN][IMG]http://t1.someimage.com/EWDQErN.jpg[/IMG][/URL]
</textarea>
</td>
```

I want to extract all the BB code from [ to ] included.

And this is my code:

```
import re
x = open('/xxx/xxx/file.html', 'r').read
y = re.compile(r"""<td> <b>BBcode</b><br /><textarea onclick='this.select();' style='width:300px; height:200px;' />. (. *) </textarea> </td>""") 
z  = y.search(str(x())
print z
```

But when i run this i get None object...  Where is the mistake?

Comment: Forgot paren `read()`.

Comment: Nothing, still get a None..  Maybe the regex is wrong..

Comment: Yeah, posted an answer.check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a parser for this:

```
from html import HTMLParser

class MyHtmlParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.convert_charrefs = True
        self.dat = []
    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.dat.append(d.strip())
    def return_data(self):
        return self.dat
>>> with open('sample.html') as htmltext:
        htmldata = htmltext.read()
>>> parser = MyHtmlParser()
>>> parser.feed(htmldata)
>>> res = parser.return_data()
>>> res = [item for item in filter(None, res)]
>>> res[0]
'BBcode'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually when i run this script and try to print res[0] i get this part of the html: box-shadow {
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #000000;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #000000;
}

Comment: Oh nevermind, i had to print 4th argument.  Exactely what i needed.  Thanks alot! One last thing, how can i write the output to a file!?

Comment: As a simple text file: `with open('filename.txt', 'w') as newfile: newfile.write(res[0])`

Comment: Glad to be of help. I noticed you're new to StackOverflow -- welcome! If this or another answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkmark on the left.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
x = open('/xxx/xxx/file.html', 'rt').read()
r1 = r'<textarea.*?>(.*?)</textarea>'
s1 = re.findall(r1, s, re.DOTALL)[1] # just by inspection
r2 = r'\[(.*?)\]'
s2 = re.findall(r2, s1)
for u in s2:
    print(u)
```

Comment: Thanks it works but it gets another part of the html because its All inside <textarea>.  I updated the question with all the html text file.  Thank you for the help btw!!

Comment: @AndrewStef Can you show some expected output. In regex problems it's always helpful.

Comment: Expecting output should be [URL=http://someimage.com/LwraZS1]          [IMG]http://t1.someimage.com/LwraZS1.jpg[/IMG][    [/URL] [URL=http://someimage.com/CDnuiST]   [IMG]http://t1.someimage.com/CDnuiST.jpg [/IMG][/URL]...  This one exactely.  The page is the output of someimage.com uploaded files.  I am trying to catch the BBCODE between [ and ] Text out of it.

Comment: @AndrewStef Try `y = re.compile(r'<textarea.*?>(?:\[(.*?)\])*?</textarea>', re.DOTALL)` and `z  = y.findall(x)`

Comment: No match found..  Unfortunately

Comment: No,  no match..  print out is []

Comment: Actually y.search find a match but its not the BBCODE,  its the Html list of uploaded images. I think this is the problem.. Theres more than one <textarea> tag in the te t..

Comment: For that change the attribute part `<textarea.*?>` to `<textarea{real attrs}>`

Comment: Yes it works,  it finds the right match.  But one last thing,   it removed all the parenthesis from the Text..  I need them cause its part of the BBCODE i need to extract.  Also, the output is every word on a new line,  how can i have it like on the html? Thanks Anyway great work..

Comment: @AndrewStef If you want the `[]` included then use `r2 = r'(\[.*?\])'`. If it works give me a thumbs up. :)

Comment: after a closer lookup it misses Text.  Inside the [IMG] [/IMG] tags is missing the url..

Comment: @AndrewStef Your wanted stuff between `[here]` and the reg gives that. The reg doesn't search for `[]here[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add something like z.group() in order to pull out of the regex object, right?  So, just changing your last line to

print z.group()

might do it.